# I Fetched All Blog Api But I want to Fetch Single Blog Post

Tags: reactjs, json, api

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Blogs.css";
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";

function SinglePost() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const fetchablog = async () => {
    await fetch("https://accounts.com/api/blogs")
      .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        return data;
      });
  };

  fetchablog();

  let singlePost = "";

  singlePost = (
    <>
      <div className="onePost">
        {data &&
          data?.datas?.data.map(({ title, attachment, content, category }) => (
            <div className="sP">
              <div className="sP_img">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <img
                  src={"https://accounts.com/" + attachment?.media_url}
                  alt=""
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
  return (
    <>
      <div>{singlePost}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default SinglePost;
```

i have Fetch all Blog Api on WebPage but now i want to show that when i click on any blog post then a Single  blog Post will get fetched.

this is the image where i fetched all blogs
[image]

But i want to show my post like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to fetch single post from the same end point with onClick event on single post.

```js
 const [singlePost, setSinglePost] = useState()

    const fetchSinglePost = async (id) => {
      await fetch(`https://accounts.com/api/blogs/${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data, "data");
          setSinglePost(data);
        });
    };

return (
<div className="onePost">
{data &&
  data?.datas?.data.map(({ title, attachment, content, category, id }) => (
    <div className="sP" onClick={()=> fetchSinglePost(id)}>
      <div className="sP_img">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <img
          src={"https://accounts.com/" + attachment?.media_url}
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
);
```